# Android Webview specific content of the page to zoom by default

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, kotlin

I am using WebView in my App when URL loaded the first time, it should show the specific content of the page to zoom by default. I have tried with zoom functions but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show specific content to the page (in a zoomed-in or zoomed-out state), you can set the scale using `setInitialScale()`

```
class WebviewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.webview_activity)
        val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.my_web_view)
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com")

        // use a number greater than 100 to zoom in closer.
        // my emulator maxes out around 470 (after which higher numbers do not make a difference).
        myWebView.setInitialScale((100 * myWebView.scale).toInt())

        myWebView.settings.useWideViewPort = true // support a wide viewport
        myWebView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true // fits contents to the screen by width
    }
}
```

I added two methods from [WebSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings): [useWideViewPort](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUseWideViewPort(boolean)) which allow WebViews to support a wide viewport and [loadWithOverviewMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setLoadWithOverviewMode(boolean)) which fits contents onto the screen by width.